# Install Vips-8.9.2 on UCRT64 windows11

Tags: c++, msys2, libtool, vips, librsvg

I am trying to install vips-8.9.2 on UCRT64 for windows 11. And after "./configure" I got:

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating vips.pc
config.status: creating vips-cpp.pc
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/include/vips/version.h
config.status: creating libvips/include/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/include/vips/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/arithmetic/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/colour/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/colour/profiles/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/conversion/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/convolution/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/deprecated/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/foreign/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/freqfilt/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/histogram/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/draw/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/iofuncs/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/morphology/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/mosaicing/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/create/Makefile
config.status: creating libvips/resample/Makefile
config.status: creating cplusplus/include/Makefile
config.status: creating cplusplus/include/vips/Makefile
config.status: creating cplusplus/Makefile
config.status: creating tools/Makefile
config.status: creating tools/batch_crop
config.status: creating tools/batch_image_convert
config.status: creating tools/batch_rubber_sheet
config.status: creating tools/light_correct
config.status: creating tools/shrink_width
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating test/variables.sh
config.status: creating test/test-suite/Makefile
config.status: creating test/test-suite/helpers/Makefile
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/libvips-docs.xml
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: creating fuzz/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing default-1 commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
* build options
native win32:                           yes
native OS X:                            no
open files in binary mode:              yes
enable debug:                           no
enable deprecated library components:   yes
enable docs with gtkdoc:                no
gobject introspection:                  yes
enable radiance support:                yes
enable analyze support:                 yes
enable PPM support:                     yes

* optional dependencies
use fftw3 for FFT:                      yes
Magick package:                         MagickCore
Magick API version:                     magick7
load with libMagick:                    yes
save with libMagick:                    yes
accelerate loops with orc:              yes
  (requires orc-0.4.11 or later)
ICC profile support with lcms:          yes (lcms2)
file import with niftiio:               no
file import with libheif:               yes
file import with OpenEXR:               yes
file import with OpenSlide:             yes
  (requires openslide-3.3.0 or later)
file import with matio:                 yes
PDF import with PDFium                  no
PDF import with poppler-glib:           yes
  (requires poppler-glib 0.16.0 or later)
SVG import with librsvg-2.0:            yes
  (requires librsvg-2.0 2.34.0 or later)
zlib:                                   yes
file import with cfitsio:               yes
file import/export with libwebp:        yes
  (requires libwebp, libwebpmux, libwebpdemux 0.6.0 or later)
text rendering with pangoft2:           yes
file import/export with libpng:         yes (pkg-config libpng >= 1.2.9)
  (requires libpng-1.2.9 or later)
support 8bpp PNG quantisation:          yes
  (requires libimagequant)
file import/export with libtiff:        yes (pkg-config libtiff-4)
file import/export with giflib:         yes (found by search)
file import/export with libjpeg:        yes (pkg-config)
image pyramid export:                   yes
  (requires libgsf-1 1.14.26 or later)
use libexif to load/save JPEG metadata: yes
```

But when try to execute make, I got this:

```
svgload.c:377:10: fatal error: librsvg/librsvg-features.h: No such file or directory
  377 | #include <librsvg/librsvg-features.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [Makefile:694: svgload.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/Marco Moreno/dd/vips-8.9.2/libvips/foreign'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:875: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Marco Moreno/dd/vips-8.9.2/libvips'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:629: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Marco Moreno/dd/vips-8.9.2'
make: *** [Makefile:536: all] Error 2
```

I´ve tried to change librsvg/rsvg-features.h name into librsvg/librsvg-features.h, and the file is on this path:"C:\msys64\ucrt64\include\librsvg-2.0\librsvg"

I will appreciate yor Help.

Also I have these warning when configure is executed:

```
configure: WARNING: Libtool does not cope well with whitespace in `pwd`
```

Comment: *"Libtool does not cope well with whitespace"* This means your build directory has spaces in the path. Try a one without them.

Comment: There's an official 64-bit build of 8.9.2 here fwiw: https://github.com/libvips/build-win64-mxe/releases/tag/v8.9.2

Comment: ... though I would build the latest version. 8.9.2 is almost three years old.

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat "Libtool does not cope well with whitespace" was solved with a path without spaces. but the "make" execution still has the same error.

Comment: Hello @jcupitt, I am trying to generate the "make" inside UCRT64 caue the project is taking all the libraries from this system and I don´t know why the project isn´t recognized the 64-bit build you suggested. the path in the environment variables is the following: C:\vips-dev-8.9\bin.